# "Windows Startup Settings" missing from Windows 10 Repair media

Tags: boot, windows-10, repair

I recently created a Windows 10 image using the Media Creation Tool. I intended to use it for getting into safe mode in another computer, but the "Windows Startup Settings" option is missing from the menu. All I have are these options:

[image]

I've searched through every option on other pages too but none of them brings up the one I need.

Why is my screen different and how to I get the correct repair image to use?